# Can't install 1.22 Google Drive version on OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Tags: macos, google-apps

On my iMac, my Google Drive icon in menu bar always says "Not logged in", and files are not synced. I have notice that on my MacBook the version 1.22 is installed, while on the iMac the version installed is 1.21. Hence the problem.

Now, when I download Google Drive to reinstall, the installgoogledrive installer always download 1.21. And when I launch the install, it says: you are using an obsolete version of Google Drive, please download the last available one.
The installer then fails.

Has anyone ever faced this problem and found a solution?

Comment: Of course, when I search on Google for 1.22 download, I have plenty of links, but it always end up to the same installgoogledrive.dmg.
I also tried to revert on my Google drive setting (web interface) go back to old version, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have found a "solution". First, I guess my problem is that I am among the new testers of the new version of Google Drive.
The solution I have found is brute-force : I copied the application straight from my macbook to my imac, rebooted and I finally able to sync files between my local google drive and the online folder.

It works, but this is not such a clean solution. When you click on the button "download Google drive" from the web interface, the installer script is supposed to determine which version you shall download, and that doesn't take early-adopters into consideration. Hopefully they will soon address this issue.